# JavaParser: parsing and generating Java code

Tags: java, javaparser

I have read the JavaParser [manual](https://javaparser.org/) and started to build my own examples. What I intend to achieve, is to read Java code and insert new lines of code on it. Specifically, I want to initialise a counter before every `if` and `while` statement, and inside the body of the statement to increment the counter. My purpose for doing this, is to run the new code for a specified set of runs and observe how many times each branch is executed. I am using JavaParser to parse and add code, because I want to generate and run everything automatically.

For example, we have the following simple piece of code:

```
if (x>4) { 
   x=4; 
} 
else { 
   x=4; 
} 
while (i<x) {
   i++;
}
```

And after the parsing I would like to have something like the following:

```
int countA=0; 
int countB=0;            
if (x>4) { 
   x=4; 
   countA++;
} 
else { 
   x=4; 
   countB++;
} 
int countC=0;
while (i<x) {
   i++;
   countC++;
}
```

My code so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {          
              CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse("class X{void x(){" +
              "    if (x>4) {  " +
              "      x=4;  " +
              "    }  " +
              "    else {  " +
              "        x=4;  " +
              "    }  " +
              "    while (i<x) {  " +
              "        i++;  " +
              "    }  " +
              "    }}");
                              
              cu.findAll(Statement.class).forEach(statement -> {             
                  if (statement.isIfStmt()) {
                      //System.out.println(statement.getChildNodes().get(0));
                     // System.out.println(statement.getParentNodeForChildren().toString());
                     // statement.getChildNodes().add(statement.getChildNodes().get(0));
                
                     // System.out.println(statement.toString());
                  }
                  if (statement.isWhileStmt()) {
                     // System.out.println();
                  }
              });
              System.out.println(cu);
            }
}
```

I have tried some things (the commended out lines) but unsuccessfully. My main problem is that I cannot find a way to inject any line of code at the end of the `childNodes` of the given `statement` which supposedly would be the increment of the counter or at the end of the `parentNode` which would be the initialisation. Is there any way to achieve what I am describing?

Comment: Perhaps a more complex example, that converts java-code to rust: https://github.com/aschoerk/converter-page/blob/master/src/main/java/de/aschoerk/javaconv/JavaConverter.java could help to understand. I normally don't change the structure created by the parser, but use a Visitor on this to create something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is the following:

```
if (statement.isIfStmt()) {
```

The condition clearly state that you are dealing with an if statement and thus you cannot actually add an instruction.
What you need to do is to get the n+1 element (where n is the index of the if statement) and then use:

```
cu.findAll(Statement.class).get(2).asBlockStmt().addStatement("countA++;")
```

There are several ways to define the expression to be added, here I'm using a plain string for clarity but check the working example for actual syntax.

For the while you can use the same technique but it's going to be more complicated. For simplicity the declarations of your counters will be added at the beginning of the method using the following approach:

```
((BlockStmt)cu.findAll(Statement.class).get(6).getParentNode().get()).addStatement(0, new StringLiteralExpr("int b = 1;"));
```

Exaplanation

- The **sixth** statement of the list of all statements is the **while loop**
- The **parent node** of this statement is the **main block** of the method and is where you want to add your instructions
- This object needs to be **class casted to BlockStm**t to be able to use the addStatement method
- **StringLiteralExpr** is a subclass of Expression and it is here used to create an instance from a string. There are many other different implementations you can explore.

I reproduced your code making a working JUnit 5 and this is the result I got

public class ParserTest {

```
String counterName = "count";
Integer counterIndex = 1;

@Test
public void main() {

    CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse("class X{void x(){" + "    if (x>4) {  " + "      x=4;  "
            + "    }  " + "    else {  " + "        x=4;  " + "    }  " + "    while (i<x) {  " + "        i++;  "
            + "    }  " + "    }}");

    cu.findAll(Statement.class).forEach(statement -> {
        if (statement.isIfStmt()) {

            // Add counter declaration in main block for the if
            String counterNameAndIndexIf = counterName + counterIndex++;
            // Create expression using StaticJavaParser
            Expression ifCounterExpression = StaticJavaParser
                    .parseVariableDeclarationExpr(" int " + counterNameAndIndexIf + " = 0");
            ((BlockStmt) statement.getParentNode().get()).addStatement(0, ifCounterExpression);

            // Add counter declaration in main block for the else
            String counterNameAndIndexElse = counterName + counterIndex++;
            // Create expression using StaticJavaParser
            Expression elseCounterExpression = StaticJavaParser
                    .parseVariableDeclarationExpr("int " + counterNameAndIndexElse + " = 0");
            ((BlockStmt) statement.getParentNode().get()).addStatement(0, elseCounterExpression);

            // Add if increment
            Expression ifIncrementExpression = StaticJavaParser.parseExpression(counterNameAndIndexIf + "++");
            ((BlockStmt) statement.getChildNodes().get(1)).addStatement(ifIncrementExpression);

            // Add else increment
            Expression elseIncrementExpression = StaticJavaParser.parseExpression(counterNameAndIndexElse + "++");
            ((BlockStmt) statement.getChildNodes().get(2)).addStatement(elseIncrementExpression);
        }
        if (statement.isWhileStmt()) {
            String counterNameAndIndexWhile = counterName + counterIndex++;
            Expression whileCounterExpression = StaticJavaParser
                    .parseVariableDeclarationExpr(" int " + counterNameAndIndexWhile + " = 0");
            ((BlockStmt) statement.getParentNode().get()).addStatement(0, whileCounterExpression);

            // Add while increment
            Expression whileIncrementExpression = StaticJavaParser.parseExpression(counterNameAndIndexWhile + "++");
            ((BlockStmt) statement.getChildNodes().get(1)).addStatement(whileIncrementExpression);

        }
    });
    System.out.println(cu);
}
```

And the result is

```
class X {

void x() {
    int count3 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    if (x > 4) {
        x = 4;
        count1++;
    } else {
        x = 4;
        count2++;
    }
    while (i < x) {
        i++;
        count3++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Let me know if you need clarifications on how to build any of these objects.
There are for sure smarter ways and code can be obviously refactored but I wanted to have it laid down as plainly as possible for you.

Cheers

EDIT: to support statement nesting and declaring the all the counter variables in the main block of the method the following can be used

```
statement.findRootNode().getChildNodes().get(0).getChildNodes().get(1).getChildNodes().get(2)
```

This approach will start top down from the root and will always point to the main block.
Use it to add your counter variables.

Comment: Very nice and understandable solution. It made me understand how to assign new expressions in the already existing code.

Comment: I have only one last question, for the shake of completing this example. When I add another ```if``` or ```while``` statement, inside the already existing ```while``` statement of this example, the initialisation of the nested statement's counter happens inside the parent ```Node```. So, every time the nested statement is executed and the condition of the parent statement is again satisfied, before entering the nested statement again, the counter will reset to zero. Should I not use ```BlockStmt``` if I want to assign all counter initialisations at the beginning of the method?

Comment: An example of what I am describing:

```while (x < 10) {
            int count4 = 0;
            x++;
            if (x < 10) {
                x++;
                count4++;
            }
            count3++;
        }```

Comment: Hi @JohnStef indeed what you describe is the actual expected behavior of the code I provided. I'm checking to see how it could support also nested statements adding counters on the root.

Comment: In order to count the number of times a statement is executed, shouldn't all initialisations be at the top of the method, to prevent resets to zero (like it happens in this case)?

Comment: Hi @JohnStef I edited my answer by adding a small paragraph at the end, please check. Regards.

Comment: Thank you @SergioArrighi